# Resolve IP to Hostname using PHP

Tags: php

How can I resolve an IP address to a hostname using PHP?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [gethostbyaddr()](http://php.net/gethostbyaddr) function.

```
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($ipAddress);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [gethostbyaddr()](http://php.net/gethostbyaddr)

```
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

echo $hostname;
```

You might find that this function can hang for some time when an address is not found - if this becomes a performance issue for you, check [this manual comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php#46869) which details a hand-coded method which supports a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

[gethostbyaddr()](http://no.php.net/gethostbyaddr)

Answer (score 0):

You should give [gethostbyaddr()](http://hu2.php.net/gethostbyaddr) a shot.